Different Search Results for Users with same Access
We have a SharePoint Classic site with a private document library that only users with permission can view. We recently a new user granted access to this library and her search results are very limited. Other users with the same level of access will receive a whole list of results and she will only get one or two with the exact same search. I re-indexed the library and it didn't have any effect. What could cause this?

Where is she searching from? The out of the box search box in the top bar is using Microsoft search, and the same is true for SharePoint.com, Office.com and Bing, if you have enabled that.
The classic search center,  if you have one of those, is using SharePoint search and most likely the same is the case for a PnP modern search page

The results in this case (one user affected) shouldn't be affected by reindexing.
Broken permission inheritance can affect what she sees. Check if she can open the files that do not pop up in the search results.
The search results can also be affected by the relevance factor. It's called relevance tuning and it's the magic that Graph, and then Copilot do for you automatically :)  If she uses more specific words can she find the missing files? Are the files she already opened/worked on coming up in search results but some old, archived ones not?
Then the relevance is the culprit.
And if nothing helps - give it a couple of days. It's not rational, but sometimes it helps.
